# MongoDb driver 2.7 query join

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to join two simple collection using the mongoDbDriver linq, but I'm having some strange problem on when trying to execute the resultant query. 
I tried to replicate the query using normal Linq so executing everything in memory and I'm not having any problem. 
Inside the constructor of PresenceSearchElement I'm doing nothing so no null exception there.

```
    var userCollection = DbContext.GetCollection<User>();
    var presenceCollection = DbContext.GetCollection<Presence>();

    var fb = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Presence>();
    var presencesList = presenceCollection.Find(fb.Empty).ToList();

    var fb2 = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<User>();
    var userList = userCollection.Find(fb2.Empty).ToList();
    //Memory query execution
    var linqRes = presencesList.Join(
        userList, 
        presence => presence.UserId,
        user => user.Id,
        (presence, user) => new PresenceSearchElement(presence, user)).ToList();
    //mongodB query construction
    var mongoDbJoinQuery = presenceCollection.AsQueryable()
        .Join(
            userCollection.AsQueryable(),
            presence => presence.UserId,
            user => user.Id,
            (presence, user) => new PresenceSearchElement(presence, user));
    var mongoDbRes = await mongoDbJoinQuery.ToListAsync();
```

And here is the stacktrace that I'm getting when executing the last line of the above code receiving a "System.NullReferenceException".

```
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.MethodCallBinders.JoinBinder.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, PipelineBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.MethodInfoMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at ....
```

I'm not sure if I'm having a bug in the driver, or I'm just doing something wrong.